# Cursor moveToPosition

Tags: android

I wish to pull out of the second row of the column NAME.

```
case R.id.buttonTest: {

    String[] projection = {DbTest.NAME};
    String selection = "_id = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(1) };
    Cursor c = sqdb.query(DbTest.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs ,null,null,null);
    moveToPosition(2);
    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbTest.NAME));
    textView1.setText(name);

}

break;
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be `c.moveToPosition(2);`?

Comment: If you're querying by `_id` and it's a primary key, you won't have two rows returned. Either way, `moveToPosition(2)` returns the third row, since it's zero-indexed.

Comment: I need to request a specific row of the column NAME. by c.moveToPosition () is not possible in my code?

Answer (score 3):

Call `moveToPosition` on reference to cursor:

```
c.moveToPosition(int)
```

Comment: I also did so? Change to the second position and requested.
 c.moveToPosition(2);

Answer (score 1):

If you`ll call

> `cursor.moveToFirst();`

then after

> cursor.moveToNext();

, you will move to the second position.

Comment: I need to request a specific row of the column NAME.
by c.moveToPosition () is not possible in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my code,

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                        if(cursor.getPosition() == position){
                           String sss = cursor.getString(0).toString();
                        }
```

}